# Laptop HDD Sparky Crackling Sound

Tags: hard-drive, laptop, hard-drive-failure

Recently my new laptop started producing this sparky, "electric" sound that is coming from hdd. It starts, I think, when the laptop warms a bit. Also my laptop becomes slow ( I guess, same reason). I've read about hdd failure and will create backup of my data.

**But the weird thing is** , if I run hdd intesive operation , like virus scan, the hdd becomes "normal" silent and computer speed returns to normal.

What am I to think of this? Is it possible that kind of continues movement stabilizes it and will intesive virus scans be bad for the drive?

hdtune gave this:

[image]

Comment: Possible hard disk failure. Check your hard drives for SMART errors [How can I read my hard drive's SMART status in Windows 7?](http://superuser.com/q/29240), and [What is the easiest method of checking SMART status for your hard drive?](http://superuser.com/q/14803). Report back with the results.

Comment: here..i added what hd tune gave me, is this what you were looking for?

Comment: See my answer [What is Current Pending Sector Count and should I worry about it?](http://superuser.com/a/1058598)

Comment: It says health status : WARNING and your hard drive is making funny noises.  Even if your hard drive was ONLY making funny noises, or ONLY giving a health status of warning, you should be concerned and backup and not use the hard drive for anything important or possibly even for anything at all. And if you have an intellectual curiosity then there are probably better avanues to persue that with than when your quirky hard drive does or does not make funny noises.