# Custom build pc is bugged?

Tags: networking, usb, windows-8.1, bios

Every once in a while my computer loses internet connection for some weird kind of reason. When I go to e.g. `192.168.178.1` it actually shows the correct login page for my modem but it just won't connect to the internet. My laptop and other devices work fine and can connect correctly to the internet.

When I restart my pc I also notice that some USB devices won't work anymore once the operating system shows up (Windows 8.1) and my background wallpaper is no longer positioned to span across two monitors either. Sometimes after serveral minutes the usb devices start responding suddenly again, but this however, takes really long.

Lastly shutting down and restarting makes my pc act kind of strange aswell. When my pc shuts itself down, the monitors lose signal (as used to and should), however my pc keeps running for another 5 to 20 minutes. When restarting, the computer will stay at the Windows 8.1 restarting screen (where it shows the loading ball thing and the text stating "Restarting...") and after it restarts, the motherboard bios screen will be shown and freeze there (cannot enter the bios and won't load operating system).

Does anyone recognize this problem and might be able to help me out?

(Are computer specifications required to answer this question? If so, please let me know in a comment so I can update the question).

Comment: Possible hard disk failure. Check your hard drives for SMART errors [How can I read my hard drive's SMART status in Windows 7?](http://superuser.com/q/29240), and [What is the easiest method of checking SMART status for your hard drive?](http://superuser.com/q/14803). Report back with the results.

Comment: The BIOS thing is pretty suspicious. I would say you have a hardware problem. I suppose you can enter the BIOS right after switching on the PC. Try safe configuration, save it and restart.

Comment: @cdlvcdlv That would work, like I said, it only happens if I click on "restart" through Windows 8.1. Restarting the pc through BIOS or on first boot I can acces the BIOS with ease.

Comment: Just a hunch, but can you replace the drive's SATA data cable?

Comment: @AndrewMorton I can but it takes a bit of time to get back at your comment as I need to open my pc and all. I will see to your comment after checking for errors through the method DavidPostill has refered me to.

Comment: @DavidPostill If I look at the first tool you refered me to, the results for my SSD (which I am using for the operating system), looks all fine. But when I look at my HDD (which I am using for anything but the operating system), at the heath tab it says: `Health status: warning` and `(C5) Current Pending Sector status warning` and `(05) Reallocated Sector Count status warning`. According to the error scan, some blocks are damaged aswell. What does this mean?

Comment: @Barrosy Imminent HDD failure: [What is Current Pending Sector Count and should I worry about it?](http://superuser.com/a/1058598/337631) - **This is a critical parameter. Degradation of this parameter may indicate imminent drive failure. Urgent data backup and hardware replacement is recommended.**

Comment: @DavidPostill Does that have something to do with my system running unstable aswell and the internet connection being all weird? Does your last comment mean I need to replace my hard drive?

Comment: @Barrosy If the OS cannot read part of the disk then anything can happen ...