# Considering severity of HD S.M.A.R.T. readings

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, bad-sectors

I found out today that my laptop's HD threw a SMART error. I've gone through the motions and did an OS partition clone and backed up valuable data. This is a work machine and I'm on a very tight budget, so buying a replacement drive is prohibitive but not impossible granted I can demonstrate the drive is beyond help and an actual risk.

Here's what I've gathered:

- `chkdsk /r` takes a long while, 1:30 hours for a 120 GB partition
- The error does appear in the event log with some rather ominous messages, these came up while the system was suspended.

(These are loosely translated from Spanish):

> (Disk) The controller detected that the device \Device\Harddisk0\DR0  anticipated that an error will occur. Please perform a backup … yada yada

And

> (DiskDiagnostic) Windows disk diagnostic detected a smart error in disk X (volumes C:\; D:\). There could be an error on the disk; please backup etc.

- The drive failed Speedfan long test
- This is the SMART reading

  ```
  Attribute              Current      Raw
  Raw Read Error Rate      99         000000030000
  Throughput Performance   100        000000000000
  Spin Up Time             230        000900000000
  Start/Stop Count         100        00000000029B
  Reallocated Sector Count 100        000000000000
  Seek Error Rate          100        000000000000
  Seek Time Performance    100        000000000000
  Power On Hours Count     82         000000001FAE
  Spin Retry Count         100        000000000000
  Power Cycle Count        100        000000000296
  GSense Error Rate        100        000000000000
  Power Off Retract Count  100        000000000012
  Load Cycle Count         95         00000000EA39
  Reallocated Event Count  100        000000000000
  Current Pending Sector   100        000000000008
  Offline Uncorrectable Sector Count  100         000000000000
  Ultra DMA CRC Error Rate 200        000000000000
  Load Retry Count         100        000000000000
  ```
- Reflect failed to make backups until I enabled file caching
- Boot, normal use and file transfers are fast as always.
- `chkdsk` (without extra paramenters) finds 4 KB in defective sectors

With all this considered, what do you think about this drive's health? I do know you can perform some tasks to force remapping (although this is a topic I'd need to research first), but what I don't know if this disk is in any position to be worth the fixes. I can provide any additional info needed for a better judgment.

I hope somebody can make something out of those weird stats!

Comment: Can you provide the error?  "With all this considered, what do you think about this drive's health?" - I would trust the fact the S.M.A.R.T error you received indicates you should replace the drive.  Of course I would use something other then Speedfan to test my HDD.

Comment: Hi! The error I got in the morning is the "loosely translated" part. What other tool do you suggest to test the drive's health? 
I also tried Victoria and CrystalDiskInfo to get second opinions but the result is the same

Comment: What's the Speedfan long test? Does it run the hard drive's long selftest? (Why is Speed**fan** even testing hard drives? Control a fan pointed at a hard drive I suppose, and getting feature-bloated?)

Answer (score 2):

Cloud backup and storage provider Backblaze [has some information that might be useful](https://www.backblaze.com/blog/what-smart-stats-indicate-hard-drive-failures/).  In particular, they note five attributes that are strongly associated with impending disk failure:

- Reallocated Sectors Count
- Reported Uncorrectable Errors
- Command Timeout
- Current Pending Sector Count
- Uncorrectable Sector Count

In your case, the drive has a nonzero raw value for Current Pending Sector Count ([see this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1058592/how-should-i-understand-current-pending-sector-count-in-crystaldiskinfo-report)). This means that while the drive hasn't actually remapped any failed sectors, it has detected that some sectors may be bad and need to be remapped the next time they are accessed.

Your drive is likely to fail soon, so you should back up its contents and replace it as soon as possible.

Comment: Thank you very much, I saw some posts by Backblaze and they were very informative. 
I've come to understand that having sectors that aren't transparently remapped in the background must mean that the disk simply can no longer fit anything below the carpet and is most likely going to fail on me sooner than later. 
I'll bite the bullet and buy a new one although I'm very curious about when would've this one finally naturally died.

Comment: "I'm very curious about when would've this one finally naturally died" - Impossible for us to answer

Comment: Does the raw value (000000000008) really means there's any current pending sectors? Or should the raw value even be looked at? I'd read that the raw values are very device-specific, and only the "Current" values are really comparable (it seems more like an art to reading smart data rather than a science). The linked question's "Current Pending Sector Count" has 96 as it's Current value, while here it's still 100

Comment: It means there's exactly 8 sectors pending reallocation. For most drives, the raw value of this attribute is the real number of sectors affected.

Answer (score 1):

This is a subjective question - because you want to know if you should continue to use the drive. We can't tell you if you should continue to use the drive - that is a decision you have to make yourself based on different factors such as the impact of downtime and data loss on your organization.

What is not subjective is what SMART is and what the error means.

**S.M.A.R.T.** (**Self-Monitoring, Analysis and Reporting Technology**; often written as SMART) is a monitoring system included in computer hard disk drives (HDDs) and solid-state drives (SSDs)[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S.M.A.R.T.) that detects and reports on various indicators of drive reliability, **with the intent of enabling the anticipation of hardware failures.**

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S.M.A.R.T.

The SMART message you provided, loosely translated means "**your drive is at risk for imminent failure**" The system designed and calibrated by the manufacturer of your hard drive has detected that the drive has degraded beyond safe limits and that it's failure is IMMINENT.

https://support.wdc.com/knowledgebase/answer.aspx?ID=251

"Long Test" failures are an additional confirmation that the drive has sustained significant physical damage and will continue to degrade taking your data with it.

**Your drive is failing and will destroy your data.** You choose if you want to keep using it.

Comment: Thanks, I will no doubt have it replaced right away